# Bot discord set custom game with app id JS

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

Hi first I'm sorry for my bad english and it's the firstime I use stackoverflow and I'm not very good with JS.

So I need some help/information for the setup of the activity of a bot:
I see one person send this [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z70VJ.png) on reddit and I see "applicationID". I would like to know if it is the same appid for creating a custom app on discord (cf: [developers/applications](https://discordapp.com/developers/applications)) and if I can with bot set up a custom game with name, pic, state (title), details, timer, etc etc like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MidJi.png). 
So I try sommething but it doesn't work :

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    client.user.setStatus('dnd')
    client.user.setPresence({
        game: {
            name: 'test1',
            type: "PLAYING",
            url: null,
            details: null,
            state: 'test3',
            applicationID: 501063122581454849,
            timestamps: null,
            party:null,
            assets: null,
            syncID: undefined,
        }
    });
});
```

I don't know if what I'm asking here is possible.

Comment: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setPresence

Comment: It's not possible to use rich presence on Discord bots. You can only set a name, type and URL using `.setPresence()`

Comment: oh okay thx a lot